# [networkx]Visualise some points on a graph, the points move along the link, but they are not nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I want to visualise some points on a graph, the points move along the link, but they are not nodes. Currently I have added some point location, but can not display them on the figure.

This is the code
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import math

#from mesa.space import NetworkGrid
#from mesa import Agent, Model
#from mesa.time import RandomActivation
#from mesa.datacollection import DataCollector
#from mesa.space import NetworkGrid
#%%Build a graph
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node("GPs")
G.add_node("AcuteCares")
G.add_node("Waitlists")
G.add_node("newPatients")
G.add_node("Preventabledeaths")
G.add_node("ReviewPatients")
G.add_node("DeathPools")
G.add_node("DNAPool1s")
G.add_node("DNAPool2s")
G.add_node("UntreatedPopulations")
G.add_node("SAPops")



labeldict = {}
labeldict["GPs"] = "GP"
labeldict["AcuteCares"] = "Acute Care"
labeldict["Waitlists"] = "Waitlist"
labeldict["newPatients"] = "New Patients"
labeldict["Preventabledeaths"] = "Preventable Deaths"
labeldict["ReviewPatients"] = "Review Patients"
labeldict["DeathPools"] = "Natural Deaths"
labeldict["DNAPool1s"] = "First DNA"
labeldict["DNAPool2s"] = "Second DNA"
labeldict["UntreatedPopulations"] = "Untreated Population"
labeldict["SAPops"] = "General Population"

G.node["Preventabledeaths"]['pos']=(0,6)
G.node["ReviewPatients"]['pos']=(-3,5)
G.node["UntreatedPopulations"]['pos']=(3,5)
G.node["DNAPool2s"]['pos']=(-3,3)
G.node["Waitlists"]['pos']=(3,3)
G.node["AcuteCares"]['pos']=(-5,0)
G.node["DNAPool1s"]['pos']=(5,0)
G.node["GPs"]['pos']=(-3,-5)
G.node["DeathPools"]['pos']=(3,-5)
G.node["SAPops"]['pos']=(-3,-3)
G.node["newPatients"]['pos']=(3,-3)

edges=itertools.permutations(G.nodes(),2)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
nx.draw(G,pos,labels=labeldict, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
#grid = NetworkGrid(G)

# %%    
def arclen(edge):
    """
    calculate the length of an edge. The format of edge is like: ('UntreatedPopulations', 'SAPops')
    """
    dist_edge = math.sqrt((G.node[edge[0]]['pos'][0] - G.node[edge[1]]['pos'][0])**2 + (G.node[edge[0]]['pos'][1] - G.node[edge[1]]['pos'][1])**2)
    return dist_edge

def patientcor(speed,step,edge):
    """get the coordinate of point along the edge, speed is the moving speed per step,
    time is the number of steps, edge is the specific edge
    """
    x=G.node[edge[0]]['pos'][0] + speed*step/arclen(edge) *(G.node[edge[1]]['pos'][0] -G.node[edge[0]]['pos'][0])
    y=G.node[edge[0]]['pos'][1] + speed*step/arclen(edge) *(G.node[edge[1]]['pos'][1] -G.node[edge[0]]['pos'][1])
    return (x,y)
#%% Visualise the graph, set the speed at 0.2, time is 0,1,2
edge=("SAPops","GPs")
for t in range(3):
    pos[t]=patientcor(0.2, t,edge) #add the location of point on the link per step to the dict
    nx.draw(G,pos, labels=labeldict,with_labels = True) #visualise pos dict along with the graph, but the additional points other than nodes do not appear on the figure
    plt.show()
```

The graph figure only displays the nodes, but not the points that move along the edges:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nx.draw` command will only plot those nodes that are in the graph.  If your dictionary `pos` provides locations of other points, it will silently ignore them.  I believe this is the appropriate behavior and I can think of lots of times where my coding would be much more difficult if it would also plot other points that appeared in my `pos` dictionary.

For what you want, simply create a new list of the points you want to plot (or in your example it looks like just a single point).  Then use matplotlib's [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) command.

```
#stuff skipped here

edge=("SAPops","GPs")
for t in range(3):
    mypoint = patientcor(0.2, t,edge) 
    nx.draw(G,pos, labels=labeldict,with_labels = True) #visualise pos dict along with the graph, but the additional points other than nodes do not appear on the figure
    plt.scatter([mypoint[0]], [mypoint[1]])
    plt.show()
```

[image: sample image]

You'll probably want to play with the node sizes and specific locations of these points.